# Group mouse event not fired Javafx

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a very simple question. I have searched the [javafx event](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/jfxpub-events.htm) page. May be I overlook some detail. Anyway if you look at my code, everything works fine.

However if I wrap the layout in a Group and add it to the scene instead of adding the layout directly, both layout and contentPane seem to stop detecting the mouse event. Event the Group, g, is not getting the mouse event.

Is such behavior normal? Why?

Any help on the subject will be greatly appreciated.

```
package mouseeventtest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MouseEventTest extends Application {
    BorderPane layout;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test Mouse Event");

        layout = new BorderPane();
        Pane contentPane = new StackPane();
        layout.setCenter(contentPane);

        layout.setOnMousePressed(e ->{ System.out.println("layout.setOnMousePressed..."); });
        contentPane.setOnMousePressed(e -> { System.out.println("contentPane.setOnMousePressed..."); });

        //Group g =  new Group(layout);
        //g.setOnMousePressed(e -> { System.out.println("g.setOnMousePressed ..."); }); 
        //Scene scene = new Scene(g, 800, 800, Color.WHITE);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 800, 800, Color.WHITE);

        scene.setOnMousePressed(e -> { System.out.println("scene.setOnMousePressed..."); });
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

     /**
      * @param args the command line arguments
      */
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(args);
     }

 }
```

Comment: Could it be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (apparently) a difference in the way `Group`s and `Region`s are sized when they are the root of a scene. A `Group` is sized to be large enough to contain its content; whereas a `Region` is sized to fit the entire scene. Since you basically have no content in the scene graph (other than some containers), the preferred size of the group is calculated as zero. Hence there is nothing to receive any mouse events.

If you add some size to your content, e.g.

```
layout.setPrefSize(800, 800);
```

then you will see the mouse events on the group, as expected.

Comment: James you are the man! :) I am new to stackoverflow. I try to mark your response as the answer but don't know how. Anyway thank you so much. Should read up more. Nowhere in javafx docs give such succinct explanation.  Thank you!

Comment: @Tania To mark the answer as correct, click on the check mark next to it.

Comment: Just checked it. I have also done further test. I notice that if I don't wrap the pane in a group, the pane will just expand to fill the scene without being specified the size, and you can also receive mouse events. However after wrapping in the group, it seems like no expansion occur and you have to specify the size as you suggest in order to receive any mouse events.